# How do I denormalize a table in power BI cell

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

[image]

The author and likes column are tables containing more than one row. How do I denormalize this in power BI?

Comment: What is the expected outcome?

Comment: I want the values for authors to be added as rows rather normalized as a table.

Comment: That's just an expand. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-expandtablecolumn

Comment: I am new to it. So, do I create a seperate column?

Comment: What's your datasource here?  Normally I'd expect to see the 'expand table' icon on columns like this.